# How to remove and add new text to span tag using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a text in `span` tag. I want to remove and new text inside that tag.

**html code**

```
<span class="mobsize-showmore-text">
        Show More
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--mini-fab mobsize-btn-downarrow">
        <i class="material-icons down-icon">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
    </button>
</span>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".mobsize-btn-downarrow").click(function () {
    $(".mobsize-div-toggle").slideToggle('fast');
    alert("mobsize-showmore-text = " + $('.mobsize-showmore-text').clone()
                               .children()
                               .remove()
                               .end()
                               .text());

    $('.mobsize-showmore-text').clone()
                               .children()
                               .remove()
                               .end()
                               .text('show less');

});
```

> I get the alert text **show more**. But it is not changed **show less** text

Comment: Why are you *cloning* your element?  It looks like you're successfully setting the text on the cloned element, but never displaying or doing anything with that element.  What was the intent of using `.clone()` here in the first place?

Comment: @David i don't want to remove the button. if it try like `$('.mobsize-showmore-text').text('show less');` it removes the button

Comment: Well, more specifically, it sets the content of the element which contains the button.  The simplest approach here would probably be to wrap the text you want to change in an element of its own so you can target that element.

Comment: @David I don't understand, can you give me sample code please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what the various calls to `.clone()`, `.remove()`, `.end()`, etc. are for, but it looks like you're overengineering this.  Specifically what's happening here is that you are successfully setting the text on a *cloned* element, but then never doing anything with that element.  The original element remains unchanged.

Simplify.

Just wrap the text you want to modify in an element of its own and target that:

```
<span class="mobsize-showmore-text">
    <span class="showmore-text-content">Show More</span>
    <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--mini-fab mobsize-btn-downarrow">
        <i class="material-icons down-icon">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
    </button>
</span>

$(".mobsize-btn-downarrow").click(function () {
    $(".mobsize-div-toggle").slideToggle('fast');
    $('.mobsize-showmore-text .showmore-text-content').text('Show Less');
});
```

Comment: could you tell me how to wrap that span and button together?